# Python 3 reading list from file- additional square brackets and quotes

Tags: python-3.x

Complete python newbie, using python 3.6 and hoping someone might be able to assist, I am trying to take an output from darknet/yolo, and compare it to a previous command output that is held in a file. I presume I am either writing or reading a list from file incorrectly as when read from file I am getting additional square brackets and quotes:

```
["['tvmonitor', 'person']"]
```

Any attempt to trim the variable with  I read it in to with [1:-1] wipes out the contents completely so presume it is counting the data being read as one item.

I taking the output from darknet/yolo which detects objects and returns a list of objects which is tagged as bytes which I then decode a utf-8.

Example code with output (see # comments -- apologies if this is incorrect way to format)

```
# define a few things to be used later
lastsaw = []
olditem = []

# r is a dummy of the output from darknet
r = [b'tvmonitor', b'chair']


print ("this is r")
print (r)
print (type(r))
#output from above code block
# this is r
# [b'tvmonitor', b'chair']
# <class 'list'>


# decode r as utf-8
seenitem = [listitem.decode('utf-8') for listitem in r]

print ("this is seenitem")
print (seenitem)
print (type(seenitem))
# output from above code block:
# this is seenitem
# ['tvmonitor', 'chair']
# <class 'list'>

# read previous runs darknet output in to lastsaw variable
# contents of file is
# ['tvmonitor', 'person']
with open("lastsaw.txt", "r") as filehandle:
 filecontents = filehandle.readlines()
 olditem = (line for line in filecontents)
 lastsaw.extend(olditem)
filehandle.close()


print ("this is lastsaw")
print (lastsaw)
print (type(lastsaw))
# output from above code block (was expecting ['tvmonitor', 'person'] ):
# this is lastsaw
# ["['tvmonitor', 'person']"]
# <class 'list'>


# diff the two lists against each other to find what is missing and what has been added

def Diff(lastsaw, seenitem):
 sawseen = (list(set(lastsaw) - set(seenitem))) 
print("This has gone::>")
print (Diff(lastsaw, seenitem))
# output from above code block (was expecting 'person'] returned):
# This has gone::>
# None

def Diff(seenitem, lastsaw):
 seensaw = (list(set(seenitem) - set(lastsaw))) 
print("This is new::>")
print (Diff(seenitem, lastsaw))
# output from above code block (was expecting ['chair'] returned):
# This is new::>
# None
```

Appreciate any insight

EDITED -- apologies could not add to comments but was queried how the list was being saved to file. The code saving the "r" list (i.e. darknet output):

This is the section where I call darknet, passing a captured image to it, I am trying to decode it from bytes before writing

```
#call darknet
if os.path.isfile("/images/img_.jpg"):
      r = (darknet.detect(net, meta, (bytes("/images/img_.jpg", encoding='utf-8'))))
      f= open(b"/output/dknet.txt","w+")
      seenitem = [listitem.decode('utf-8') for listitem in r]
      f.write ('%s' % seenitem)
      f.close ()
```

later in the script I copy the new file over the previous with so it is lastsaw.txt for the next run

Comment: It would be better to save the data as json using `with open('my_file.json', 'w+') as f:` and `json.dump(f, my_lst_or_dict)`.  (I may have the parameters backwards off hand and the extension can be anything).

Comment: My `.dump()` parameters in the commend above are backwards, Object goes first then the file handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of your file has one line:

```
['tvmonitor', 'person']
```

`.readlines()` returns a list of all lines in a file as a list of strings.
So:

```py
with open("lastsaw.txt", "r") as filehandle:
    filecontents = filehandle.readlines() # This contains ["['tvmonitor', 'person']"]
    # olditem = (line for line in filecontents) # This line does nothing relavent
    lastsaw.extend(olditem) # This adds "['tvmonitor', 'person']" to your lastsaw list
```

So you can do one of two things.

The first option (and the one I recommend the most) is read the file as a json file (provided all text in the file is valid json):

```py
import json
# Other code...
with open("lastsaw.txt") as filehandle:
    # Note you can do this: lastsaw.extend(lst)
    # Or you can just assign it right away:
    lastsaw  = json.load(filehandle)
```

Alternatively, the less ideal option, is to use `ast.literal_eval` which can evaluate strings as literal python objects such as strings, integers, lists, etc.:

```py
import ast
# Other code...
with open("lastsaw.txt") as filehandle:
    lastsaw  = ast.literal_eval(filehandle.read())
```

Also please use at least two or four spaces for indenting python code, it is a lot more readable. (4 spaces is the most common).

-- Edit --

As for the dif, use zip to combine the two lists:

```
lastsaw = ['1', '2', '4']
seenitem = ['1', '3', '4']
# if len(set(x)) > 1 -- The length of the set will be 1 if they match
# else if will be longer than 1 element thus this condition.
dif = [
    (indx, x) for indx, x in enumerate(zip(lastsaw, seenitem))
        if len(set(x)) > 1
]
print(dif)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. Switching to json does appear to have resolve the issue though unfortunately the diff statements still output none. I'll try to fix that one myself and duly noted on the indenting (I probably should switch to a better text editor as well)